# Keras Custom Loss Function accessing Additional Parameters during Training only

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to introduce additional constraints to my network by exposing additional input data to the custom loss function during training but not when predicting.

My model basically is `ay+b=x` with `y` the ground truth, `x` the measurement and `a`,`b` additional parameters that I know during training (working with synthetic data) but not when predicting.

Currently I have `x` as my training inputs, `y` and my expected outputs and use a mean squared error as a loss function. Writing a custom loss function with only this data is pointless as I only have access to `y_true` and `y_pred`. Needless to say, my network is not performing that great.

I would like to expose the `a` and `b` terms to my custom loss function during training, without them becoming an input to my predictive model. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks